# What would reach the ground first?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, drag, free-fall

Hi I’m trying to get my head round this if a bowling ball and coin from the Empire State at exactly the same time what would hit the ground first I know that gravity = 9.81ms-2 but what else am I missing?

Comment: Does this help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681278/

Comment: Depends how complicated you want to do this... Just the equivalence principle? Air resistance? Wind currents? Not clear from your question.

Answer (score 2):

> but what else am I missing?

Air resistance. In the absence of any atmosphere they will indeed fall at the same speed and arrive at the ground at the same time. See this famous video of a hammer and a feather being dropped on the moon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDp1tiUsZw8

Air resistance however makes this much more complicated but the bowling ball will get there first.